# apache mod rewrite condition - rule

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I would like to grab the url, check if the url contains "#!" and redirect to the same url without the "#!" string? I tried the following - but this is not working?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "(.*).html#!$"
RewriteRule "(.*)" $1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that one:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ".*\.html#!$"
RewriteRule "^(.*\.html)#!$" $1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the previous solution was wrong. The server will not process the data after the grid symbol:

```
[27/Oct/2016:10:23:12 +0300] domain.com xx.xx.xx.xx xx.xx.xx.xx 200 0 0.000 HEAD /index.html HTTP/1.1 - curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3

$ curl -I 'http://domain.com/index.html#!1asfasgf1ghgh'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.1
Date: Thu, 27 Oct 2016 07:23:14 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 9977
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Sat, 23 Jan 2016 14:06:07 GMT
ETag: "a66b6-26f9-52a00d64891c0"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```